# How can I download a file with wget for which url is generated by the website?

Tags: firefox, curl, download, wget

A website generates a zip file for download upon clicking the download button. I want to download it using wget. I tried cancelling the download and trying to copy the download link, however it was just the general url of the website and not a download link. I tried opening developer tools and clicking "copy POST data" to get

```
 csrfmiddlewaretoken=FPsq2lfGy******7file_B****001=on
```

and by clicking on copy as cURL:

```
curl 'https://f********.eu/download/' -H 'Host: f****5-db.s***t.eu' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Referer: https://*******.s***t.eu/files/****/******' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Cookie: csrftoken=FPs********qGy; sessionid=a4l4zaqtrtpvwts7pbadw9ny' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' --data ''
```

I tried using the previous answers, but couldn't understand how this file can be downloaded. Please explain.

Comment: What exactly did you try? What happens if you simply run the curl command you just found?

Comment: It returns an html file which has the title "403 forbidden", and the body is "CSRF verification failed. Request aborted". Is it because somehow the port is closed after cancelling the file download? Also, it is not possible to pause the download, it stops after that.